# Rename excel file depending on Access Table first field

Tags: ms-access, vba, file-rename

By using VBA Access ,I want to copy excel and rename it depending on Table first field.
In below example,

For example, instead of using fixed name like:
FileCopy "C:Documents\Folder\CurrentFile.xlsx", "C:\Documents\New Folder\NewFile.xlsx"

I want to use:
FileCopy "C:Documents\Folder\CurrentFile.xlsx", "C:\Documents\New Folder\NewFile" **& [Table1]![Feild1] &** ".xlsx"

Comment: You could probably get that single value using DLookup https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937

Comment: Okay.... so, ...what's the problem? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Abdul Sounds like you know what you need to do.  Was there a question?  Might be a good idea to check out the [help/on-topic] as well as how to create an **[mcve]** and also "[ask]".  (Welcome to [so]!)

Comment: The issue this command not work: FileCopy "C:Documents\Folder\CurrentFile.xlsx", "C:\Documents\Folder\[Table1]![Feild1] & ".xlsx".

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Are you getting an error?   Is the application crashing? ...Perhaps `Field` is misspelled?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if `[Table1]![Field1]` returns the string to replace *only* `CurrentFile` then you could use:

```
FileCopy "C:\Documents\Folder\CurrentFile.xlsx", _
         "C:\Documents\Folder\" & [Table1]![Field1] & ".xlsx"
```

**...so:**

- `C:Documents` was missing a `\`
- `NewFile" & [Table1]![Feild1] & ".xlsx"` was also missing a `\`
- `[Feild1]` may need to be spelled `[Field1]` (unless the misspelling was intentional)